# load page content before iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, document-ready

I have an html page that has quite a few iframes imbedded amongst some text. When you click the text a transition displays the iframe.
the html code:

```
    ...some text <span id="firtsLink" class="link">clickable text</span>
<span><iframe id="frame" src="iframe.html"></iframe></span> some more text...
```

This works well, but because I have about 8 iframes, the page loads a bit slowly. I don't want to get rid of the iframes, but I would like to use jQuery to load the page content (text etc...) before it loads the iframes. Ideally I would like to prioritise the first iframes if possible. I am fairly new so I am looking for a relatively simple solution. Thanks for your time.

Comment: the browser loads the page ... use jquery to load the iframes on document ready

Comment: Don't use iframes, especially for displaying content that you control. If you are already set on using jquery, just use the concise [jquery `.load` method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) to bring the content in with AJAX `$('#someDiv').load('iframe.html')`